# Show that the normalizer of Cartan subalgebra is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

When I was reading Brian C Hall's book: *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*, it said

> It is a straightforward exercise to verify that the normalizer
>   $$N=\{A\in SU(3)~|~\mathrm{Ad}(g)\mathfrak{h}\subset \mathfrak{h}\}$$
>   is a subgroup of $SU(3)$, where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Cartan subalgebra of $SU(3)$.

To show $N$ is the group, everything is trivial to me except that the inverse is in $N$, that is,

> if $g\in SU(3)$ such that $$\mathrm{Ad}(g)\mathfrak{h}=g\mathfrak{h}g^{-1}\subset \mathfrak{h},$$
>   then we have $g^{-1}\mathfrak{h}g\subset \mathfrak{h}$.

Since $\mathfrak{h}$ is generated by two elements 
$$H_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0 &0 &0 \end{pmatrix},\ \ \ H_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0 &0 &-1 \end{pmatrix},$$
suppose $A=(a_{ij})\in SU(3)$ and $A^{-1}=(\bar{a}_{ji})$, then we can do the direct and brutal computation, which is too much work. So I was wondering if there is any simple and elegant method?

Is it true that 
$$N=N':=\{A\in SU(3)~|~\mathrm{Ad}(g)H=H\},$$
where $H$ is the corresponding connected Lie group of $\mathfrak{h}$? If so, then $N'$ is obviously a group and we are done.

I can only prove that $N=N'':=\{A\in SU(3)~|~\mathrm{Ad}(g)H\subset H\}$.

Comment: Remember that in inclusion in the definition of $N$ is of finite dimensional vectorspaces of the same dimension.

Comment: In each of the definitions, there is an $A$ on the left and a $g$ on the right. Is that intentional ?

Comment: Is it true that $N$, the normaliser, is actually just those group elements generated by the Cartan subalgebra itself? schematically $N=e^{i\mathfrak{h}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint (expanding Tobias Kildetoft's comment): This has nothing to do with Lie groups and Lie algebras, let alone specific matrix calculations. Rather, let $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ be any group homomorphism (i.e. representation of an arbitrary group $G$ on an arbitrary vector space $V$), and let $W$ be a *finite-dimensional* subspace of $V$. Show that

$$G_W := \{g \in G: \rho(g) (W) \subseteq W \}$$

is a subgroup of $G$, by using that (by a well-known linear algebra result about injectivity and surjectivity of endomorphisms of finite-dimensional vector spaces) the inclusion $\subseteq$ in the definition can be replaced by an equality $=$.